# Regex digit and dot(point) from a combined String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have got a String for example.

```
"Quantity : 2.85 kg"
```

Here I only need to extract the number with exact configuration `2.85`.

`String.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");` only extracts number as `285`, but I need 2.85.

Kindly help.

Comment: You could directly match `\d+(\.\d+)?` to extract the number

Answer (score 1):

You must be kidding guys, the pattern for a digit is

```
p = "/d*(./d+)?"
```

and extract it is :

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p)
while(m.find()) 
res = m.group(0)
```

Comment: No it is not. Your pattern actually does not work. You have to escape the d with a backslash, you have to escape the dot to match it literally and because everything is optional it would also match an empty string.

Comment: ok its then "((//d*([.]//d+) | //d+)"  , forgot that in java you cant control how greedy * is. Other patterns are worse in this answer

Comment: I am afraid that is also not correct. `((//d*([.]//d+) | //d+)` is missing a parenthesis, you have to use a backslash instead of a forward slash. With those corrections these are the matches which I think is not what OP is meaning to match. https://regex101.com/r/x2akHU/1

Answer (score 1):

Regex is any character, then one or more digits with a dot and following two digits, space and kg.
A capturing group is used to capture the part thas is to be extracted.

```
String test = "Quantity : 2.85 kg";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d+\\.\\d\\d) kg");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

if(matcher.matches()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}else{
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```